# Pycharm 2017.1.2 says "Nothing to show" under package installation panel

Tags: python-3.x

In **settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> + sign**,
earlier, i could search all the packages which i want to install but now i can't search any library.

I tried clearing **invalidated caches** and restarted Pycharm number of times.
But it did n't work.

Under Manage repository, tried adding :-
https://pypi.python.org/pypi
https://pypi.python.org/simple

both together and individually.
But still No packages are shown in the panel.
Can any one help ??

I have **windows 10 version** and **Pycharm Community Edition 2017.1.2** with **pip 9.0.3**